# Reading response stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to edit the response body in .NET Core 2.2. I am able to successfully read the request body but not the response body. I have tried calling `context.Request.EnableRewind();` before reading the stream of the body with no success.

I am trying to read the body of the response at the end so I can do the reverse of what I am doing in the request. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to read the response body so that I can change it? This is in an ASP .NET Core Web API - I am trying to modify the response body using middleware.

My code is as follows

```
using (var bodyReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
{
    //Read the request body
    var bodyAsText = bodyReader.ReadToEnd();

    //Get the password for the private key
    var keyPass = _configuration["PrivateKeyPassword"];

    //Declare variable that will hold the key pair
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

    //Read the keyPair from the private key
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Keys\private.key")))
        keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader, new PasswordFinder(keyPass)).ReadObject();

    //Deserialize the JSON body into object
    // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
    var e2eData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<E2EModel>(bodyAsText);

    //Create the decrypt engine to decrypt the data
    var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
    decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);

    //Base64 Decode the key and IV
    var keyEncryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(e2eData.Key);
    var ivEncryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(e2eData.IV);

    //Decrypt the key and iv
    var key = decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(keyEncryptedBytes, 0, keyEncryptedBytes.Length);
    var iv = decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(ivEncryptedBytes, 0, ivEncryptedBytes.Length);

    //Convert the key and iv to string to trim it before use
    var keyStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(key).Trim();
    var ivStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(iv).Trim();

    string decryptedBody;

    //Decrypt the body with AES256 using key & IV derived above
    using (var aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyStr), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivStr));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(e2eData.Data)))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) 
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                    decryptedBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Write the bytes into the memory stream
    injectedRequestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decryptedBody), 0, decryptedBody.Length);
    //Set the seek to the begin on the stream
    injectedRequestStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    //Set the context request body to the new stream
    context.Request.Body = injectedRequestStream;
}

//Let the call through the remaining stack
await _next(context);

context.Request.EnableRewind();

var body = new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  The response body has to come from the server.  So are you getting a response.  I would start by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and make sure of the following 1) You are getting a response 2) The Status of the response is 200 DONE 3) Make sure you code is getting the same number of bytes in the response.  You will get an exception of you do not have the entire response body.

Comment: This is in the middleware of a Web API, I am trying to encode the Response that is going to be returned to the API caller. It's not a response being read from an external server, it is its own response.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  It is still IP and it can still be seen in the sniffer.